# End User License Agreement for an Open Source Project

Tags: open-source, licensing, eula

Every now and then I publish some source code/sample/snippet, etc in my blog and I'd like people to download and use it freely But I'd want my contact info remain in the files' headers wherever my code is used. Something like:

> /* My super cool open source thingy
>   * Copyright (C) 2010 Kamyar Paykhan
>   * This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
>   * modify it. But you MAY NOT delete this header information including
>   * software author, website and this agreement.
>   *
>   * This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
>   * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
>   * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
>   *
>   */

But since I'm not a native english-speaker, I'd appreciate if anyone shows a good template with proper phrases.
P.S. I'm not really interested in licensing my codes under GNU, MIT and prefer a REAL simple custom license with a few lines.

Comment: what kind of protection are you looking for? do you want to be protected against your application being used for something you never intended (and your name being dragged into trouble)? if so, use the more common licenses. lawyers drafted these. real simple could be real foolish.

Comment: This question is off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Creative Commons](http://creativecommons.org/) has a [tool](http://creativecommons.org/choose/) to help you pick a license based on your needs.  You put a short mention of the license in your code and refer them to the full license.

Comment: thanks for the link. However I wonder what options I should check to exactly achieve what I have in mind. meaning people can do whatever with my code. Just let my specifications (more specifically, my website address) remain on the file header. Could you please clarify this for me?

Comment: @Kamyar that tool is available in many languages--pick your language from the selection at the bottom and you should be good.